# Go to a specific offset in a document

Tags: shell, text, editor, sublimetext

I need to debug some parts of an Xtext project, in a ILocationInFileProvider. In my debug session, I obtain at a point some Region objects containing an `offset` and a `length`. I want to visualize in the original text file which part is matched by this `(offset, length)`.

Is there a shell command or a tool (I tried in Sublime Text, Gedit, Geany, without success) which provides a "select" or "goto" feature, allowing to display / select / highlight an area in a document based on these informations ?
If possible, I would like to perform this simple task in a Linux environment. Even a simple "jump to position" could be useful. Any idea ?

Comment: Is the offset in bytes?

Comment: I don't know exactly what is the meaning of the "offset" I manipulate. It is filled by Xtext framework. But since my documents are in UTF-8, without any special char, each char is 1 byte long. I check in Gedit, and the byte length is strictly equal to number of chars in the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vim, to go to offset 1234, do one of

```
:goto 1234<cr>
```

or, in normal mode

```
1234go
```

This counts in bytes, not characters.

Comment: This works great, thanks ! I am not a vim expert, I often don't use it... But this answer helped me. I only wait a few to accept the answer, since I am curious to see if a graphical text editor also have this feature

Answer (score 2):

This isn't very elegant, but you can use `dd` to pick out bytes of a file. And if you use `vi`, you can shell out and do it quite easily.

For example:

```
echo Freddy Frog | dd iseek=3 bs=1 count=5 2>/dev/null
ddy F
```

It looks like Ubuntu uses skip, not iseek:

```
echo Freddy Frog | dd skip=3 bs=1 count=5 2>/dev/null
```

That sets the blocksize to 1, and seeks 3 bytes into the input stream and shows you the following 5 bytes.

If you use it with a file, it would be:

```
dd if=yourfile iseek=3 bs=1 count=5 2>/dev/null
```

If you want to simplify things, you can put that in a script and save it as "view"

```
#!/bin/bash
dd if="$1" bs=1 skip=$2 count=$3 2> /dev/null
```

and do

```
chmod +x view
```

Then you can type

```
view yourfile 1200 100
```

**Note**: If you don't set the `bs=1`, it gets a default value of 512, then your iseek would be 3x512 bytes, not 3 bytes...

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 14.04, dd is version 8.21. Operand iseek is not recognized. I try to use seek instead, but this doesn't work. `dd if=./myfile seek=8390 bs=1 count=7 2>/dev/null` returns the 7 first chars of my doc